# why am i seeing inconsistencies between two blowfish implementations?

Tags: java, c++, encryption, blowfish

I am encrypting "06.93308" using the key "rubicon" first with javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec and another in C++ using openSSL. However both are giving me different encrypted values. The java version gives me hex `A834BDD6C3478B8C` whilst the OpenSSL gives me `D06D7CB756744903` which is considerably different. The aim is to get the same result as the java equivalent. Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

the java code is as follows:

```
char[] password = new char[] { 'r', 'u', 'b', 'i', 'c', 'o', 'n' };
byte[] raw = encrypt(password,"06.93308" );

    private static byte[] encrypt(char[] password, String plaintext) throws Exception {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[password.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length; ++i) {
                    bytes[i] = (byte) password[i];
            }
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "Blowfish");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes());
            return encrypted;
    }
```

the c++ side is as follows:

```
   CBlowFish oBlowFish((byte *)"rubicon", 8);

   char encryptedPrice[17] = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
   char myBidPrice[] = "06.93308";
   encrypt(myBidPrice,encryptedPrice);


    void encrypt(char bidPrice[],char encryptedPrice[])
    {
        oBlowFish.Encrypt((unsigned char*)bidPrice, (unsigned char*)encryptedPrice,8 );
    }
```

this is the openSSL code which gives me the same result as the above C++ code

```
#define SIZE 16

unsigned char *out = (unsigned char *)calloc(SIZE+1, sizeof(char));
BF_KEY *key = (BF_KEY *)calloc(1, sizeof(BF_KEY));
BF_set_key(key, SIZE, (const unsigned char*)"rubicon" );
BF_ecb_encrypt(in, out, key, BF_ENCRYPT);
printf("%s\n",out);
```

Comment: And what does the `Encrypt` method of `oBlowFish` look like?

Comment: updated take a look, essentially it is using standard openssl calls similar to this link here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225996/blowfish-c-does-not-correctly-encrypt-decrypt-why

Comment: sorry pasted the wrong line, now corrected, please take a look

Comment: not my choice to use blowfish, just the nature of things :)

Comment: CBlowfish isn't OpenSSL.

Comment: `CBlowFish oBlowFish((byte *)"rubicon", 8);` -- is BlowFish storing a reference to the string or does it copy the string? If it doesn't copy, you get a dangling reference which may be the source of error.

Comment: well spotted Sami, i have used a number of implementations in C++ all giving me the same results, let me updated with openssl code

Comment: ok updated please take a look

Comment: Could you replace the two outputs with their hex dump?

Comment: sure for the java the hex value is A834BDD6C3478B8C and for the c++ it is D06D7CB756744903

Comment: I don't get this line `BF_set_key(key, SIZE, (const unsigned char*)"rubicon" );`, "rubicon" is not 16 bytes long.

Comment: Why isn't this giving any of your results? `echo -n "06.93308" | openssl enc -bf-ecb -nosalt -K 72756269636f6e -nopad | hd`

Comment: the key length was wrong! When i adjusted that i was getting correct results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rubicon" is not 16 bytes long. You'll have to adjust `SIZE` accordingly.